# Simplifying code of complex list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, simplify, simplification

Assume a list of dictionaries (`lst_of_dcts`) in Python. Further, assume that I wish to modify (e.g., encode in ASCII) each value `v` of the key-value pairs `k:v` in each of the dictionaries `dcts`. In order to do so, I am using list comprehension, but the code line becomes quite long and difficult to read.

```
import unidecode
[{k: unidecode.unidecode(v.decode('utf-8')) for k, v in dct.items()} for dct in lst_of_dcts]
```

How would you split the above list comprehension into shorter, easier-to-read lines? (Please note that I don't mean to simply reformat the lines via, for example, backward slashes.)

Comment: you call that complex? I don't. I call that pythonic.

Comment: change the import to `from unidecode import unidecode`, and other than that it's fine!

Comment: You could use regular `for x in xs:`, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please note that I don't mean to simply reformat the lines via, for example, backward slashes.

Why not? That's exactly what I'd do to make it more readable. Properly indented, of course, to show the structure:

```
[{k: unidecode.unidecode(v.decode('utf-8'))
  for k, v in dct.items()}
 for dct in lst_of_dcts]
```

Comment: Fair enough. You convinced me.